# NoMethodError when trying to reference a column from a different table - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have two tables Head and Category

In head.rb

```
has_many :categories
attr_accessible :name_subcategory, :quote, :statement
```

In category.rb

```
belongs_to :heads
attr_accessible :image_url, :string, :title, :show_on_home_page, :show_on_category_page, :show_in_footer, :float_subcategory, :name_subcategory
```

In my view file

```
<% @category.each do |category| %>
<%= category.heads.name_subcategory %>
<% end %>
```

At runtime I get the following error:

> undefined method `name_subcategory' for nil:NilClass

I'm pretty new to rails so I think this has something to do with not making the proper relationships between the tables but I'm pretty stumped as to the exact problem. I tried to research the error but it seems to be very broad and can be caused by a wide range of problems and I'm having trouble pinpointing exactly where I'm going wrong.

I hope someone here can help!

**Edit**
What I'm trying to achieve: Each head contains many categories and I'm trying to print out the head associated with a particular category (I know the naming is strange, this is a team project that I've only just joined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the relation should be

```
belongs_to :head   #note: head is singlular
```

As Marek Lipka said, one of the category could have a `nil` head. So you could do

```
<%= category.heads.name_subcategory if category.heads %>
```

OR

```
<%= category.heads.try :name_subcategory %>
```

Remember to change the method call to `head`, if you change the relation

Comment: I changed the relation to the singular version. Thanks a lot for this answer, it's not giving the output I want but at least I have a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is that `Category#head` for at least one `Category` record returns `nil`.

The way to fix this error depends on what you want from this association. If you want every `Category` record has its `Head` associated, you may use `validations`. You should also name association properly, `belongs_to` association name should be singular.
Example is given here:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :head
  validates_presence_of :head
end
```

You may on the other hand have an error in setting the association. Given `head` variable contains reference to `Head` instance and `category` is `Category` instance, you should set association with:

```
category.head = head
```

Comment: Ok, well what I'm trying to do is print out the head associated with a particular category. I'm not sure where the nil record is coming from because every category is associated with a head.

Comment: @twirlingtornadoes if you want to debug your problem quickly, you can type:
`<%= @categories.map{|category| [category.id, category.head]} %>`
somewhere in your view and run this code. 
Also, your associatian naming is wrong, check out my answer now, as I edited it to reflect this fact.

Comment: @Marek_Lipka This may be a newbie question but does validates_associated :head make sure that category is referencing a head? Or something like that?

Comment: @twirlingtornadoes It was my mistake - `validates_associated` runs validations of associated model when your original model is saved. What you need is probably `validates_presence_of :head`, which is in my answer now.